# Subscribe in subscribe in Angular rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscribe, rxjs-observables, rxjs-subscriptions

I have:

```
getSth(): void {
    this.service.functionName.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroy$),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map(res => res.event)
    ).subscribe(((response) => {
      this.getAnother(response);
    }));   }

getAnother(response): void {
    this.anotherService.anotherFunctionName(response).subscribe((res) => {
      this.result = res;
    });   }
```

I know that isn't a good solution to write subscribe in subscribe. How to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Let's use [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) :

```js
getSth(): void {
  this.service.functionName.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    map(res => res.event),
    switchMap(response =>
      this.anotherService.anotherFunctionName(response)
    )
  ).subscribe(response => this.result = response);
}
```

Comment: Or you could use [mergeMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap) if you don't want the inner Observable to be cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

You have more options, there are some `*map` operators, that handle the flow differently. By your example you could use [switchMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap), which cancels your running observable (in your example the `getAnother`).
There's a [Operator Decision Tree](https://rxjs.dev/operator-decision-tree) in the docs, try it, it can help a lot.

**You get `switchMap` with this logic:**

1. I have one existing Observable, and
2. I want to start a new Observable for each value
3. and cancel the previous nested Observable when a new value arrives
4. where the nested Observable is calculated for each value

One other note, you should have your [`takeUntil` to be placed last.](https://cartant.medium.com/rxjs-avoiding-takeuntil-leaks-fb5182d047ef)

You could write something like this:

```js
getSth(): void {
  this.service.functionName.pipe(
    // If service.functionName returns a new object every time distinctUntilChanged will do nothing as references won't be the same.
    // distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap(resp => this.anotherService.anotherFunctionName(resp.event))
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    ).subscribe((result) => {
      this.result = result;
    }));
}
```